# Html or Aspnet button on ColorBox Popup Redirect to another aspx page on button click

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I am stuck with a critical issue.Can some one please suggest.

I have an `.ascx` page on which there is a pop up which has an aspnet button which must redirect to another page on click.

I followed the following steps:

- On ascx page after opening colorbox, this function is called on clicking the button.

  ```
  $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: "/HomeLoan/ProductConfirmationPop_SaveData.aspx/btnSaveData",
       contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function (response) {
              alert(response);
       },
       error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              alert(XMLHttpRequest + textStatus + errorThrown);
       }
    });
  ```
- On aspx page

  ```
  [WebMethod]     
  public static void  btnSaveData()
  {      
    function sahil();//this function i want to call after this function is being called               
  }
  ```

I am getting Json parse error.

I removed `dataType:json` and made it return a `html/text` then it is giving me object object error.

Comment: btw, `[Object object]` isnt an error. Try logging it and showing it here. Log it like this : `console.log(response)` instead of `alert(response)`

Comment: I am unable to debug the code..If ajax call is working then it will come in my breakpoint but it is not coming..

Comment: Then its going into the error handler?

Answer (score 0):

This would propably be a lot easier if you could use a simple html form, add the value to a hidden input when onsubmit is triggered, and post it to a webservice which will redirect for you.

---

Anyway:

You need to decorate your btnSaveData method with another attribute and change the return type / parameter to string (or any other type that suits your needs):

```
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    [WebMethod]
    public static string btnSaveData(string color)
    {
         // do sth with the color 

         return "/SaveSuccess.aspx";
    }
```

And in js:

```
    // retrieve the color as a string (this is up to you - I don't know what sort of ColorPicker you're using, so this is a placeholder)
    function saveColor()
    {
        var color = $('#myColorPicker').color.toString();

        // create the data for the webmethod,
        // the parameternames have to be the same as they are on the WebMethod
        var colorData = "{ color:'" + color + "'}";

        $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: "/HomeLoan/ProductConfirmationPop_SaveData.aspx/btnSaveData",
             contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
             dataType: 'json',
             data: colorData,
             success: function (response) {
                window.location.href = response.d; // redirect on success
         },
         error: function (response, text, error) 
         {
                alert(response + ' ' + text + ' ' + error);
         }
    });
```

---

Hope this helps and works!

Comment: I am getting ObjectObject Parse ERROR-sYNTAX eRROR iNVALID CHARACTER

Comment: If the syntax error you were getting was inside the webmethod, I just added the missing ";"